# naming a finance management / tracking application

Tags: naming

I am about to start develop a finance/expenses tracking/management/statistics webapplication, somewhat similar to xpenser.com , mint.com (except bank integration), for a college project and I am looking for a name

credit will be given in the documentation if the name will be used

if this turns later into a real-life project the name will be changed

...
unsure if this belongs on stackoverflow, but I figured that since it is a programming project here is a place to ask for ideas

Is your question about programming? - It is related to programming
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed. - there many answers, they don't need discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas off the top of my head:

- BigSpender
- st@tement
- Fiscality
- My Online Money - It's as safe as Mom!
- ManEx - Manage Expenses
- you could call it Dave and say that "Dave is your own personal accountant" (Or Doug or any "accountant sounding name")
- Ponzi/Madoff etc.
- BudgeIT

Dodgy Abbreviations:

- F.U.N - Financial Upkeep (unification/utility etc) Notepad
- C.A.S.H - Comprehensive Allocations and Spending Hub (or Homepage etc)
- S.P.E.N.D - Secure Personal Expense Needs Database

As this is a homework product, I wouldn't worry too much if you infringe on an existing trademark.
you mention XPenser, so why not eXpenserER - The expense tracking application for Economic Reliability. Or, a common mispelling of something in the related field (like XPenser is Expenser).

Whenever naming things for Uni, I tended to try and be humorous and serious at the same time. Whilst the name would be funny, I would then treat it as a normal name and the Branding was normally conservative.

Good Luck1

Comment: accepted answer for the extra recommendation, have not decided yet about the name

Answer (score 1):

- Scrooge
- pennypincher
- frugality
- moolah
- dough
- bling
- inmymattress

Answer (score 0):

MyMoney, ISpent, ImBroken... It depends from what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:
 - MoneyWatcher
 - MoneyFlow
 - The Honest Accountant

Also I am mad for recursive acronyms so something like:
SOFT Online Financial Tracker